# Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

How to type of return value in stored procedure. And what are difference between them. Please explain me.

Comment: Check out http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Stored_Procedures_-_Output_Parameters_%26_Return_Values - This lists the different options for returning values with examples

Comment: Please explain what you mean a little further, im not sure what ur really asking

Comment: First of all: they are called "store*D* procedures" - as in "stored in SQL Server" (not "store procedures")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically with stored procedures you expect to get back a dataset. If your looking for a way to get single values back from some type of query, you might be better suited making a UDF (user defined function).

Nonetheless, here is how you can create a stored procedure with an output variable

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetNameByID (
    @ID NVARCHAR(50),
    @PersonName NVARCHAR(50) OUTPUT )
AS
SELECT @PersonName = LastName
FROM Person.Contact
WHERE ID = @ID
```

with this procedure, you can then execute it as follows.

```
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(50)

EXEC dbo.GetNameByID 
    @ID = 'A123FB',
    @PersonName = @Name OUTPUT

SELECT Name = @Name
```

Good Luck.